# Problema envio de correo Powershell + smtp gmail

Tags: email, powershell, smtp, error404

Estoy intentando hacer un envío de correo electrónico a través de Powershell y a la hora de ejecutarlo me da este error

```
Send-MailMessage : El certificado remoto no es válido según el procedimiento de validación.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
```

Tengo todo activado en las preferencias de gmail de IMAP y lo de las aplicaciones no seguras y me sale dicho error.
¿Alguna solución? Muchas gracias
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo, al hacerlo en Máquina Virtual, el firewall del antivirus me bloqueaba la conexión y no podia hacer absolutamente nada. Desactivandolo, se soluciona el problema, o bien configurandolo correctamente. Muchas gracias y disculpadme